# Why is there different behaviour from getpwuid and getgrgid?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpython

In Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5, `grp.getgrgid` is capable of accepting a string:

```
from grp import getgrgid
print(getgrgid('0'))
```

However, `pwd.getpwuid` can't do the same:

```
from pwd import getpwuid
print(getpwuid('0'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getpwuid_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(getpwuid('0'))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

This is because inside `Modules/pwdmodule.c`, `getpwuid` uses `PyNumber_ParseTuple` with a converter that uses `PyNumber_Index` to get a Python integer, and that raises an exception on failure.

However, in `Modules/grpmodule.c`, `grp_getgrgid` uses `PyNumber_Long`  (Or `PyNumber_Int` for an old enough Python) as a conversion first, and as the documentation says at https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html, this is the equivalent of running `int(o)`, which can convert a string to an integer. Only then is it given to `PyNumber_Index`, by way of a helper function `_Py_Gid_Converter`

What is the reason for this difference? Is it a deliberate choice based on some history?

The behaviour of `getgrgid` seems more helpful, and it's odd that it doesn't apply to both functions. Is this undesirable behaviour in `getgrgid` or `getpwuid`?

Comment: This is a good question. I think it might get a more official answer on [one of the official Python mailing lists](https://www.python.org/community/lists/). Doing so may eventually lead to getting one of the two modules patched. The mailing list for development of the core python code is [python-dev](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev) (the core developers are on there, including Guido).

Comment: Good plan. I raised a 'behaviour' class issue at https://bugs.python.org/issue26129 just after posting this, but you're right that I should ask the python-dev list.

Comment: If I were you, I would just write a patch with the more relaxed behavior for `pwd` and attach it to the ticket. It is more likely to get changed if the patched code is already ready to merge in. Also, I doubt they would make it more strict for `grp` since there may already be code in the wild that depends on the relaxed behavior. You should probably add regression tests with the patch as well (for both the [`pwd`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/test/test_pwd.py) and [`grp`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/test/test_grp.py) modules).

Comment: Going by https://bugs.python.org/issue26129 the developers decided `getgrgid`'s behaviour was undesirable, and it will be deprecated in the next release.

Comment: After reading their rationale on the bug report, I agree with them. Python is a strongly typed language; letting it behave like anything else can only cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because humans are fallible and mistakes happen.  Some are [doozies](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=definition+doozy) and [get noticed quickly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/), others are minor and can go years without detection.

Thank you for helping make Python better!